# CakePHP cakeError()?

Tags: cakephp, error-handling

I can't find any information of where `cakeError()` is defined as member-function. The [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1188/Error-Handling) only states that the call looks like this:

```
$this->cakeError(string $errorType [, array $parameters]);
```

But calling this in my *AppController* subclass gives me `Call to undefined method EntriesController::cakeError()`.

Where is `cakeError()` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CakePHP 2.x:**

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/errors.html

> For 2.0 Object::cakeError() has been removed. Instead it has been
>   replaced with a number of exceptions. All of the core classes that
>   previously called cakeError are now throwing exceptions. This lets you
>   either choose to handle the errors in your application code, or let
>   the built in exception handling deal with them.

**CakePHP 1.3:**

http://api13.cakephp.org/view_source/object/#line-187

http://api13.cakephp.org/class/object#method-ObjectcakeError

Comment: Thanks, must have missed that. I'm using *2.x*.